# Rotate an object around an orbit

Tags: three.js

[This is the work I have done so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAvlg.png) I am working with Three.js animation in which I want to create a solar system. And I want to make the planets revolve around the sun. I have done my work up to creating orbits around the sun. But I don't know how to make the planet revolve on the particular orbit. I have created an orbit and planet like this.

```
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 'aqua'});
var geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(3.2, 1000);
geometry.vertices.shift();
var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
line.position.set(0.5, 5, 6);
line.rotation.x = 2;`

geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 32, 32);
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'yellow'});
p1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
p1.position.set(3, 3.8, -1);'
```

So, I want to make the planet revolve on the particular circle.

Answer (score 8):

You know the distance from the Sun to the planet (radius), then you can use `Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()` functions to achieve what you want.

```
var orbitRadius = 10; // for example
var date;
```

In the animation loop you can do:

```
date = Date.now() * 0.0001;
p1.position.set(
  Math.cos(date) * orbitRadius,
  0,
  Math.sin(date) * orbitRadius
);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/a2ogz9vx/) example

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/g14z6nyk/2/ for an updated version without errors for the OrbitControls and degToRad calls.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do is to create a Three.js object representing the orbit an add the circle and the planet to this orbit. This way, you just need to change the rotation of the orbit to make the planet revolving around the sun.

```
var orbit = new THREE.Group();
orbit.add(line);
orbit.add(p1);
scene.add(orbit);
```

Then, in your rendering loop :

```
orbit.rotation.y += 0.01;
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Note that if you want to change the tilt of the orbit, you'd have to give the orbit a new rotated parent.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y8hL7aek/9/).

**Edit***

If you don't want to manually animate inside the rendering loop, you can also use [tween.js](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/) to create the animation.

```
// make 1 revolution in 5 second
var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(orbit.rotation).to({y: Math.PI / 2}, 5000);

// and start again
tween.onComplete(function () {
    orbit.rotation.y = 0;
    tween.start();
});

tween.start(); // kick off the animation
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y8hL7aek/8/) for Tween.